# Hashmap inside a hashmap not removing the keys using remove?

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap

This is my list.

```
list = Stream.of(
        "06|20|1",
        "11|20|2",
        "11|20|2",
        "07|207|6",
        "11|207|2",
        "07|207|6",
).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I have a hashmap such as:

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
HashMap<String, String> newHash = new HashMap<>();
```

And my code is

```
for (String line : list) {
    String key, value, priority;
    key = line.split("\\|", -1)[1];
    value = line.split("\\|", -1)[0];
    priority = line.split("\\|", -1)[2];

    if (hashMap.containsKey(key)) {
        HashMap<String, String> getPriority = hashMap.get(key);
        Map.Entry<String, String> entry = getPriority.entrySet().iterator().next();
        String oldKey = entry.getKey();
        String previousPrior = getPriority.get(oldKey);
        if (Integer.parseInt(priority) > Integer.parseInt(previousPrior)) {
            getPriority.remove(oldKey);
            getPriority.put(value,priority);
           hashMap.put(key, getPriority);
        }
    } else {
        newHash.put(value, priority);
        System.out.println(newhas);
        hashMap.put(key, newhas);
    }

}
```

I want to have the have the key with highest priority only such as:

```
{20={11=2},207={07=6}}
```

as 11 and 7 has the highest valaues in 20 and 207.

But i am getting all values in the inner hashmap.

Comment: Unrelated. read about java naming conventions: variable/field names start lower case, and `Map` is a bad name for a variable anyway: never use names that overlap with java standard class names.

Comment: What's the point of a map with only one entry?

Comment: And then: please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. And then: it sounds like you want to sort your entries. Sorting would definitely require to LOOP over your content ... multiple times. But there is only one loop in there?

Answer (score 2):

How about using streams instead?

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = list.stream()
        .map(line -> line.split("\\|"))
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(line -> Integer.parseInt(line[2])))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                line -> line[1],
                line -> Map.of(line[0], line[2]),
                (low, high) -> high));
```

[**Ideone Demo**](https://ideone.com/ANGgyL)

Answer (score 0):

For each new key that you insert in your `Map` variable in the `else` condition of your code you need to create new `HashMap` to insert it along with the new key.
What you are doing is using the same `newhas` variable for all the keys in your `Map` variable.
So change this

```
        else {
            newhas.put(value, priority);
            System.out.println(newhas);
            Map.put(key, newhas);
        }
```

to

```
       else {
            newHas = new HashMap<>();
            newhas.put(value, priority);
            System.out.println(newhas);
            Map.put(key, newhas);
        }
```

[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/W5o0Jn)